# Aurora like software for ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, 3d, animations, logo

Actually, I'm really new to ubuntu and i've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and i'm in need of a software, Aurora 3D Animation Maker in win OS. Or any other similar software would also be a good option. Please let me know if got anything. As i've searched and didn't found anything like Aurora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try Blender (https://www.blender.org), or just google for `linux 3D animation software`